# Speed up DNS propagation time

Tags: domains, dns

I want customers who buy a domain and hosting services from me to be able to use their website right away and build in WordPress but they have to wait for their new domain to propagate. I don't want a temp URL and no hosts file editing as it can be difficult for customers new to this. I have custom DNS servers so would making the TTL very low work or would there be a downside? Would having a CDN speed things up? Any advice would help.

**More info:**
Customers purchase a WordPress install and domain name via WHMCS and I resell the domains through Enom. After that, an account is created under that domain in WHM and WordPress is installed.

Comment: No a CDN will not work, why would it? a CDN is used for serving cookiless static files. A TTL determines the time between changes which is pretty irrelevant because if your customers are registering a new domain and hosting then there should be no wait... since when creating the domain you can assign the correct DNS entries meaning there is 'no' TTL. If they already have a domain pre-purchase then you are subject to the TTL set by DNS servers across the globe, but please note that 5min TTL's are generally ignored... most servers set their own times and widely reject TTLs set in the DNS zone

Comment: The only reasons why your customers domain/hosting is not setup straight away is if you changed the settings of the DNS after they registered the domain or they are using their own domain... either case you need to wait, you have no control on EXTERNAL DNS servers other than TTL's which are widely ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am just worried about new domains for now because they are the most common. I resell domains through Enom so when they purchase a new domain it will almost instantly point to my server?

Comment: Also, I heard that CDNs can eliminate propagation times but now I see that it is for if you are making IP changes and not actual DNS changes.

Comment: CDNs have nothing g to do with DNS. They utilize two completely different protocols and have two distinctly different purposes. It is like asking if a potted plant can speed up your Yugo. Propagation is completely out of your control. Using your own NS does nothing and will even slow propagation down. Leave it up to the experts and use a quality registrar with a large infrastructure.

Comment: @SimonHayter do you have any source for "most" servers ignoring TTLs? That has not been my experience. billy9811: it might help if you could add a bit more info about your current process to your question - you register a domain for a customer, do you then immediately change the name servers? What sort of delay are you seeing?

Comment: I added more info...

Comment: You are going to have to think of it like ordering a mobile phone service, there is a short waiting period that can't be avoided.

Comment: @TimFountain it's pretty much common knowledge that DNS servers particular those at the ISP level do not respect short TTL's. Broadband providers mostly CACHE DNS records which mean the TTL is completely ignored and the cache is updated according to their own intervals, DYN post here: https://dyn.com/blog/ttl-override-by-isps-is-there-a-performance-cost/ this is caching, but even some DNS servers without cache can, and do ignore low TTL due to overhead.

Comment: @SimonHayter So true. Short TTL times were set mostly by web hosts and registrars as a way of increasing responsiveness, however these times were 5 minutes or less so caching became a problem. Most telecoms completely ignore TTL times and cache for a set period regardless. This is common knowledge if you work in the industry like I did or are paying attention like we are.

Comment: Most web hosts offer the sub-domain while waiting because what alternative is there? Propagation takes time. No way around that short of having the customer change their client computer to use the registrar's DNS.